# in surveymonkey, where do I find the api_key

Tags: surveymonkey

My console app that grabs survey responses from SurveyMonkey stopped working.
WHere do I get the api_key from? Is it the same as "Client ID"?
and is the authentication token the "Access Token"?

Answer (score 1):

What specifically is broken about your app? What is being returned? On what requests? Are you hitting `/v2` endpoints or `/v3` endpoints?

New apps created on SurveyMonkey (or whenever you refresh your client credentials) no longer use an API Key (it has been discontinued). All you need to make requests for new apps is the access token.

For OAuth, the same thing - nothing has changed except the API Key is no longer a required field.

See the documentation about it [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#authentication).

Comment: I am trying to use v2 (and yes, I know it goes away soon!)
I am not using oauth, just a simple access to grab responses internally. So the url changes from https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_respondent_list?api_key=__________"
to just 
https://api.surveymonkey.net/v2/surveys/get_respondent_list
?

THe error I am getting is 400, bad request!

Answer (score 1):

You can find your credentials [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/apps)